# Adjusted and Unadjusted OR's with greg package

Tags: r, logistic-regression, summary

I am trying to create a table for crude unadjusted and adjusted odds ratios. My code is as follows:

```
model<- glm(lead_ind ~ hseAge+ DurStayCat + 
                       gender + Region + 
                       ips_parasites, data=DfStudy2sel)

printCrudeAndAdjustedModel(model)
```

However, my output is a table of the betas and their confidence intervals. How can I get the ORs, 95%CI instead? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not doing a logistic regression but a plain gaussian. You need to specify that you are using a binomial family, here's an example:

```r
library(datasets)
data(mtcars)
mtcars$am <- factor(mtcars$am, labels = c("Automatic", "Manual"))
fit <- glm(am == "Automatic" ~ cyl + mpg, data = mtcars, family = binomial)

library(Greg)
# Drop the intercept column via the -1 as it is rarely used in logistic models
printCrudeAndAdjustedModel(fit)[-1,]
```

Comment: second question: can I create latex tables from the output?

Comment: I don't use Latex as it frequently causes issues when compiling. Take a look at the Hmisc package that has the latex function which I used as inspiration for my htmlTable function. It will require a bit of coding in order to get it to work

Comment: Hi @MaxGordon, I get an error `Error in desc_mtrx[, c(1, 3), drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds` when I add `desc_column=TRUE` e.g. `printCrudeAndAdjustedModel(fit, desc_column=TRUE)[-1,]`, any Idea?. Please let me know If I need to start a new question. Thanks for your time and help.