# Displaying all rows in Library(Greg) package

Tags: r

I used the approach (library(Greg) in the link below for my unadjusted and adjusted OR summary and it was very useful.
However, my last few rows (data fields are cut off), is there a way of increasing the number displayed rows.

[Adjusted and Unadjusted OR's with greg package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38314849/adjusted-and-unadjusted-ors-with-greg-package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Greg::printCrudeAndAdjusted` function outputs an htmlTable that should not be truncated. If you are using `Greg::getCrudeAndAdjusted` you may have a `tibble` that is truncated and then you can see the entire thing with `print(n = 1e4)`.